# Changing the number of columns in archive pages in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How can I change the number of columns in archive pages in woocommerce?

It shows 3 in shop pages, but 4 in archive pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This snippet code will change the number of products per page on all archives pages:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

**Advice:** Sometimes, is necessary to change some css rules, to get the correct display per row.

> **If you want to target some specific archive pages** you can use [WooCommerce conditionals tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) in an if/else statement [as in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932094/woocommerce-changing-the-number-of-product-categories-per-row/38933787#38933787)

---

**References:**

- [Change number of products per row](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/)
- [WooCommerce conditionals tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)
- [WooCommerce - Changing the number of product categories per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932094/woocommerce-changing-the-number-of-product-categories-per-row/38933787#38933787)