# How to change the number of product categories per row using WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I'm using Woocommerce settings to show categories thumbnail on the initial shop page and then products and their thumbnails within them.

I want to have that initial category page to display 3 thumbnails per row and the products page to show 5 categories per row.

To display 5 products per row I've used:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
    return 5;
    }
}
```

This changes the thumbnails per row on the category page AND on the shop page too.

Does anyone know how I can change the categories page to 3 thumbnails per row and maintain 5 products per row on shop page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [WooCommerce conditionals tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/), will help you to achieve that. I have changed your code:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        if ( is_product_category() ) {
            return 3;
        } else { // for other archive pages and shop page
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

**Advice:** Sometimes, is necessary to change some css rules, to get the correct display per row.

> **WooCommerce conditionals tags usage:**
>
> To target **shop page** archive:
>
> ```
> if ( is_shop() ) {
>     // return the number of items by row
> }
> ```
>
> To target **product tag** archives:
>
> ```
> if ( is_product_tag() ) {
>     // return the number of items by row
> }
> ```
>
> To target **all product archives** except **product category** archives *(adding* **`!`** *at the beginning)*:
>
> ```
> if ( !is_product_category() ) {
>     // return the number of items by row
> }
> ```
>
> And you can also **define** some particular **categories** or **tags** *(see the documentation for that)*.

---

References:

- [WooCommerce - Change number of products per row](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/)
- [WooCommerce - Conditionals tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: Only use if ( is_product_category() ) { return 3; } else { return 5; }. This way you are not using the same variable twice (3)

Answer (score 0):

In my storefront-child theme. The accepted answer did not work for me. I had to copy woocommerce/templates/loop/loop-star.php to my child theme subfolder /woocommerce/loop/ and modify it like this:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

// FMP20181126 - Categories are SubCategories set # of columns.
$display_type = woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode();
if ( 'subcategories' === $display_type || 'both' === $display_type ) {
        wc_set_loop_prop( 'columns', 3 );
}   

?>

<ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this code:

```
/**
* Change number or products per row to 3
*/
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
    if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
        function loop_columns() {
        return 3; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```